# Installed pylint extension in vs code but it isn't identifying mistakes

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

Screenshot of what's enabled:

[image: Screenshot of what's enabled]

I installed latest version of Python 3.9.4 and also checked it in command prompt it was working well.
But as I installed VS Code and also the python extension and made a file in order to check pylint, but pylint is not working even I have enabled it as you can see in image, so what can I do now?

Comment: read the VSC doc of Python testing: `"python.linting.enabled": true,`

Comment: yes in settings.json file "python.linting.enabled": true, but still it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Make sure you've installed pylint to current selected interpreter.

Run `pip show pylint` to see if it's located in current environment.

2.Check if you set `Jedi` as `"python.languageServer"`.

Cause if I set Jedi on my machine, the linting won't work. It's recommended you install [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) extension and in `Settings.json` set:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance"
```

Comment: @Mukul Sharma. Glad my answer helps you. It's appreciated that you [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) it for more people with the similar question to reach this solution.